# Regex skip &shy; to find a match

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have strings in my MongoDB database that contain `&shy;` character (for word-breaking purposes).
I want my expression to as well match the terms that contain it (as if they don't):

```
search term: haha 
output: haha, hahaha, ha&shy;ha
```

Comment: There's no concept of skip in regular expression. That means you have to always consume. So if you want to find `ha` and `ha&shy;ha` use star like `ha(&shy;)*`

Answer (score 1):

It needs to convert INPUT each char into Carriage Return "CR", because CR can be anywhere:

```
let text = "hohoho, hehehe, ha&shy;ha";
let input = "haha"
let cr = "&shy;"

// convert CR into REGEX format
let crr = "(?:"+cr+")?"

// split string into 1 char array
let input_split = input.match(/.{1}/g)
// add cr regex to char
let r = input_split.map(function(i)
{
    return crr+i
});
// array to string + last regex
r = r.join('')+crr

console.log(r)


r = new RegExp(r, "i");
let m = text.match(r)

console.log(m)
```

open console to see working:

https://jsfiddle.net/1d2m7jb0/1/

Output example:

```
(?:&shy;)?h(?:&shy;)?a(?:&shy;)?h(?:&shy;)?a(?:&shy;)?
[
  'ha&shy;ha',
  index: 16,
  input: 'hohoho, hehehe, ha&shy;ha',
  groups: undefined
]
```

Comment: Thanks. We found a way to do it with $addFields and $replaceAll, $match on this new field.